# Extract part of the first line of a file

Tags: shell, text-processing

I am trying to configure some external commands in Gedit3, for compiling LaTeX files. All works well, except for the following. I have a LaTeX document, consisting of many parts. Each file begins with

```
% mainfile: name_of_main_file.tex
```

So in bash I'm trying to extract the first line of each file, and from that line extract `name_of_main_file.tex` and compile that. So the question is: what is the quickest way of extracting `name_of_main_file.tex`, loading it into a variable, say `$MAINFILE`, so that then I can compile that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.tex; do
  read _ _ mainfile < "$file"
  echo "$file : $mainfile"
done
```

*Note*: I am assuming the files you want to extract the first lines from are `.tex` files, if this is not the case then change the `*.tex` part accordingly

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm. Thanks! The loop is actually unnecessary for me, since what I'm really trying to accomplish is this: I have a file opened in gedit, which is not necessarily the master LaTeX file, but its first line tells me what the master file is. I am trying to extract that line and compile the master file. Anyway, thanks for your help, it works!

Answer (score 3):

This should do the work (untested):

```
sed -sn 1p *.tex | cut -f2 -d: | xargs latex
```

Comment: (+1) especially for the reminder about `sed -s`...

Comment: Do you maybe want to add `sort -u` to cut down on the duplicates passed to `xargs`?